# Show Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider the following data type

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a
```

I'm trying to define an instance of Show (without importing any modules or using deriving) that would display the tree like so

```
Main*> let a = Branch "x" (Branch "y" (Leaf 4) (Leaf 7)) (Leaf 9)
Main*> a
"x"
     "y"
          4
          7
     9
```

So far, this is what I've come up with

```
findDepth (Leaf a) = 0
findDepth (Branch a (b) (c)) = 1 + (max (findDepth b) (findDepth c))
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
     show (Leaf x) = show x
     show (Branch a (b) (c)) =
          show a ++ "\n" ++ s2 ++ show b ++ "\n" ++ s2 ++ show c ++ "\n" ++ s1
               where
                    d = findDepth (Branch a (b) (c))
                    s1 = addSpace (d-1)
                    s2 = addSpace d
                    addSpace n = replicate n '\t'
```

Unfortunately, this indents the nodes with the lowest depth the most and the highest depth nodes the least. I know that the findDepth function should actually be giving leaf the greatest value and branch the lowest value, but can't figure out a way to write the function recursively for both arguments. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't think that this is a duplicate of the other question, feel free to add a comment (don't forget to add `@Zeta`). That being said, you can still accept one of the posted answers. By the way, is there currently some kind of Haskell lecture? Some of the latest questions were quite similar.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is no need for additional `findDepth` function - you could easily traverse through the tree and increase the depth each time you shows the children:

```
import Text.Printf

data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf a

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
  show = showAtLevel 0
    where
      showAtLevel l (Leaf x) = addSpace l ++ show x
      showAtLevel l (Branch x (lt) (rt)) = printf "%s%s\n%s\n%s" (addSpace l) (show x) (showAtLevel (l + 1) lt) (showAtLevel (l + 1) rt)
      addSpace = flip replicate '\t'
```

Test cases:

```
*Main>  let a = Branch "x" (Branch "y" (Leaf 4) (Leaf 7)) (Leaf 9)
*Main> a
"x"
    "y"
        4
        7
    9
*Main> Branch "x" (Branch "y" (Leaf 4) (Branch "z" (Leaf 42) (Leaf 314))) (Leaf 9)
"x"
    "y"
        4
        "z"
            42
            314
    9
```

Comment: Holy cow thank you so much

Comment: @Alec, you are always welcome!

Comment: Is there any reason why you none of the four answers (counting those in the other question) tried a recursive approach without `replicate`, like `show tree = unlines (map indent (go tree)) where
        go (Leaf v)       = [show a] ;
        go (Branch v l r) = show v : indent (go l ++ go r);
        indent = map ('\t':)`?

Comment: Just copied some of the OP code in order to minimize changes. Interesting approach using `unlines`, seems pretty clean. Don't you want to post it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint without he whole solution: Write a single function `showWithDepth :: Int -> Tree -> String` that passes down the "accrued depth" so far. Then you can write `show = showWithDepth 0`.

Note that in general you *shouldn't* write `show` instances like this, as its "semi-standard" that show instances should work essentially like the derived ones and generate something resembling valid Haskell code. (And additionally, in the presence of a `Read` instance, we want `read . show === id`.